# Jboss clustering replication time

Tags: time, jboss, load-balancing, session-replication

I am using a clustering setup for my application in which i am using mod_cluster as load balancer and Jboss as Application server.Basically whenever a nodes fail it takes some time(in my case it's 10-15 sec) to replicate the entire session to another node even though it forwards the requests to the new node immediately but it take at least 10 sec to replicate entire session ,if i try to access that application before that 10 sec time than page shows session expired but if i try to access it after 10 secs it works perfectly.So basically wants to know why is it taking so much time even though my session has only 1 variable of few characters and how can i minimized this time?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. you tagged this as [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka "clustering", a data mining technique). You probably meant [tag:load-balancing].

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of your AS? There were some problems with early builds of AS7 in the past: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1755